# Detecting handwritten digits from image in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to detect handwritten digits from images. The images contain tables within which the digits are written. How can I localize and detect digits in each box. I am new to image processing so any idea how to do this will be greatly appreciated. The image is given below:

[image]

I have tried using erosion and build up to find the structure of table. But I am stuck on how to proceed further finding boundaries and contours.

```
img = cv2.imread(image_name)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, img_bin = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

if type == 'h':
    structuring_element = np.ones((1, 50), np.uint8)
elif type == 'v':
    structuring_element = np.ones((50, 1), np.uint8)

erode_image = cv2.erode(img_bin, structuring_element, iterations=1)
dilate_image = cv2.dilate(erode_image, structuring_element, iterations=1)
```

Comment: Threshold on red, get contours and get their bounding boxes.

Comment: @stateMachine how to perform these actions